# How to update image file binding to Image control?

Tags: wpf, file, binding, overwrite

My app includes a Image control which has binding to a disk image file. I some condition, the image file need be updated. But the updating can't be done because the image file is open and can not be overwritten. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the binding, so the image will not be used by your program
than overwrite the image file
and than re-add the binding

i'm not sure about this, but it's worth a try

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried  `BindingOperations.ClearBinding();  img.Source = null;GC.Collect()`  but the image is still write protected.

Answer (score 0):

Now my solution is:
To use a converter to convert the image path into BitmapImage.
in the converter, load the image using a FileStream and copy the data into a MemoryStream and finally close the FileStream.

```
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bmp.BeginInit();
        var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
        memStream.Flush();
        fileStream.Close();
        bmp.StreamSource = memStream;
        bmp.EndInit();
        return bmp;
```